# Funções com parâmetros opcionais Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu quero criar uma função que tem o **primeiro** parâmetro opcional.

Por exemplo: a função `range([start, ] stop [, step])`

Assim, se somente um argumento for passado ele é considerado como o segundo parâmetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em python normalmente não é necessário fazer sobrecarga de funções pois é uma linguagem dinamicamente tipificada e suporta a passagem de argumentos opcionais paras as funções.

Na maioria dos casos basta fazer a verificação dos parâmetros:

```
def teste(begin=0, end=None):
  if end is None:
    for i in range(begin):
      print(i)
  else:
     for i in range(begin, end):
      print(i)

teste(10)
teste(10,20)
```

Código no Rep.it: https://repl.it/repls/HeartfeltJumpyFiletype

Porém em um caso ou outro você poderá necessitar simular uma sobrecargas de funções e para isso pode utilizar a biblioteca [Multiple Dispatch](https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/).

Apenas decore as funções a serem sobrecarregada com `@dispatch` seguido dos tipos dos argumento.

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch


@dispatch(int, int, int)
def teste(begin=0, end=1, skip=1):
  for i in range(begin, end, skip):
    print(i)

@dispatch(int)
def teste(end):
  for i in range(end):
    print(i)


@dispatch(int, int)
def teste(begin=0, end=1):
  for i in range(begin, end):
    print(i)


teste(10)
teste(11,20)
teste(21,30,2)
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/AffectionateIllfatedExecutable

Nos bastidores essa biblioteca cria um objeto `Dispatcher`que usa um decorator para armazenar diferentes implementações da função e para o programador cria uma função de mesmo nome que seleciona entre diferentes implementações baseado nos parâmetros passados.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar `*` para passar ilimitados valores como parâmetro ou então *keyword arguments* para definir uma chave e valor.

Após isso, você precisaria administrar os argumentos passados, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
def simula_range(*args):

    start = 0
    step = 1
    stop = args[0]

    if len(args) > 1:

        step = args[2] if len(args) > 2 else step

        start = args[0]
        stop = args[1]

    print("Start =", start, "Stop =", stop, "Step =", step)
```

Se você quiser algo menor, você pode utilizar parâmetros pré-definidos e verificar se o parâmetro `stop` possui um valor ou não.

Se ele não possuir valor, você deve trocar o valor de `start` pelo de `stop` e vice-versa. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
def simula_range(start, stop = 0, step = 1):

    if not stop:
        start , stop = stop, start

    print("Start =", start, "Stop =", stop, "Step =", step)

simula_range(2)      # Start = 0 Stop = 2 Step = 1
simula_range(3,7)    # Start = 3 Stop = 7 Step = 1
simula_range(3,7,2)  # Start = 3 Stop = 7 Step = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é alguma espécie de Range que você está fazendo?

Da maneira que você descreveu não é possível, ou ao menos eu nunca vi algo do tipo. Se um parâmetro é opcional, ele precisa ter um valor default, e também os parâmetros seguintes precisam ser opcionais.

Você poderia declarar o segundo e terceiro parâmetros como opcionais, iniciando o segundo com `None`, e então verificar dentro da função se você recebeu algo nesse segundo parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
def range_test(start, stop = None, step = 1):
    if stop == None:
        start, stop = 0, start

    print(f'Range de {start} a {stop}, incremento de {step}')


range_test(10) # Range de 0 a 10, incremento de 1
range_test(5, 10) # Range de 5 a 10, incremento de 1
range_test(0, 20, 2) # Range de 0 a 20, incremento de 2
```